# Is it safe to execute user-provided code in R using an environment containing only safe functions?

Tags: r, security, sandbox

An example is an R calculator, callable e.g. by `rcalc.R "log(10*2)"`:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
# rcalc.R, an example R calculator

# Create evaluation environment without predefined functions
myenv = new.env(parent=emptyenv())

# Define names of R functions which are allowed for calculation
allowedFunctions = c("+", "-", "*", "/", "^","exp", "log")

# Assign the functions to the evaluation environment
for(name in allowedFunctions){
    assign(name,match.fun(name), envir=myenv)
}

# Read in a user command ...
userCommand=commandArgs(TRUE)[1]
# ... parse it, execute it and print it.
eval(parse(text=userCommand),envir=myenv)
```

Examples:

```
rcalc.R "log(10*10)"
## [1] 3

rcalc.R "list.files('.')"
## Fehler in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
##   konnte Funktion "list.files" nicht finden
## Ruft auf: eval -> eval
## Ausführung angehalten

rcalc.R "library('base')"
## Fehler in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
##   konnte Funktion "library" nicht finden
## Ruft auf: eval -> eval
## Ausführung angehalten
```

Is it possible to break out of this sandbox by a command line input of the script in order to execute arbitrary code?

My motivation is a plotting script, which lets users print out mulitple plots while reading in the input data only once. The idea is them being able to specify custom plot commands on the command line, as well as some simplified data reformatting commands, derived from `cut`, `as.factor` etc.

Comment: Did you try using `eval(ls(),envir=.Global)` as argument to your code ? I assume it would work and so your answer would be "No" (but that's a guess).

Comment: If you impose some rigidity on the input, you could write your own mini-parser that only allows these functions. You might also be interested in the [RAppArmor package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RAppArmor/index.html).

Comment: @Tensibai that command  is not accepted, because it doesn't find the eval function. It also doesn't find the .Global variable. This 'attack' seems to be not possible

Comment: Yep I did dig a little and it's not that simple, but using primitive functions I'm pretty sure you may escape it) sounds an interesting challenge